# Solvability Condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

How do we find the solvability condition for the given equation,

$$-u''-u=f,\hspace{0.5cm}-\pi<x<\pi,\hspace{0.5cm}u(\pi)-u(-\pi)=0,\hspace{0.5cm}u'(\pi)-u'(-\pi)=0$$

Comment: What basis of functions? You can express this in very many different ways.

Comment: I believe the forcing function $$f$$ is to be determined as to give a periodic solution. Sorry for the missing information

Comment: Okay. This looks to me like a differential equation in which you usually solve for the function which has different differentials occuring, in this case that would be $u$.

Comment: I'm trying to find the solvability condition $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx=0$$ but I have no idea where to start with this. I tried finding the general solution $$u$$ which has form $$C_{1}sin(x)+C_{2}cos(x)$$ but I'm not sure that this is the correct step to find $$f(x)$$

Comment: Both sin and cos have integral mean value $0$ over one period. A linear combination of functions which do have this property can never escape this property.

Comment: $u(x)=1$ solves the DE and the BC with $f(x)=-1$, so that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx=-2\pi\ne 0$. The hypothesized integrability condition is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking that $u$ should have a continuously differentiable $2\pi$-periodic extension. In that case the Fourier series of 
$$
u(x)=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}c_ke^{ikx}
$$
has to satisfy
$$
\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}c_k(k^2-1)e^{ikx}=f(x)
$$
and by extracting the coefficients
$$
2\pi(k^2-1)c_k=\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-ikx}f(x)dx
$$
This directly tells you that this is only possible if
$$
0=\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\pm ix}f(x)dx
$$

---

One could also get this directly from the solution formula
$$
u(x)=-u(-\pi)\cos(x)-u'(-\pi)\sin(x)-\int_{-\pi}^x\sin(x-t)f(t)\,dt
$$
with
\begin{align}
u'(x)&= u(-\pi)\sin(x)-u'(-\pi)\cos(x)-\int_{-\pi}^x\cos(x-t)f(t)\,dt
\\
u''(x)&= u(-\pi)\cos(x)+u'(-\pi)\sin(x)-f(x)+\int_{-\pi}^x\sin(x-t)f(t)\,dt
\end{align}
so that indeed $u''(x)+u(x)=-f(x)$ and the boundary conditions read
\begin{align}
u(-\pi)=u(\pi)&=u(-\pi)-\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin(\pi-t)f(t)\,dt
\\
u'(-\pi)=u'(\pi)&=u'(-\pi)-\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos(\pi-t)f(t)\,dt
\end{align}